# What kind of component I should use to inform a user that an action has been completed successfully?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app where the user can download a photo. After downloading it, I want to display a small message saying "Download successful". Initially I wanted to show `Modal` from https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal but then I wanted this info to disappear either in 5 sec, or if the user taps outside of the modal. So I thought I should wrap my `Modal` inside an `Animated` component https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations

Am I on the right track? Is this the way to show a user friendly message - wrapping modal inside animated. Or there is another component which I can use?

Comment: Hi! I think you question belongs to and will be better answered on UX stack exchange. Please refer to this community: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not so sure.... I just feel like I am not aware of an appropriate component, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better if you use SnackBar for such purposes.

You can use any snackbar library in your project. Your wrap it around with your project, Then whenever you need to throw information message or error message you just called the hook for that snackbar. Also it will automatically disappear after showing the message. you won't need to take care of seconds.

notistack package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/notistack
You can also checkout the Material UI Alerts.